# Why does Java's main method use String[] instead of String dot dot dot

Tags: java

An array parameter declaration causes a syntax error **where the invocations happen**.  Yet the main method uses String[] instead of String...  How can I understand this inconsistency?

```
package domain.test;

import utilities.CConsole;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        t.method1(0); // the array will exist but have a length of zero
        t.method1(0, (Object[])null); // the array will not exist
        t.method1(0, "a");
        t.method1(0, "a", "b");
        CConsole.pw.format("\n");

        t.method2(0); // the array will exist but have a length of zero
        t.method2(0, (String[])null); // the array will not exist
        t.method2(0, "a");
        t.method2(0, "a", "b");
        CConsole.pw.format("\n");
    }
}

class Test1 {
    void method1(int number, Object... args) // Object[] causes syntax errors
    {
        if (args == null)
            CConsole.pw.format("args == null\n");
        else
        {
            CConsole.pw.format("args != null    ");
            CConsole.pw.format("args.length %d\n", args.length);
        }
    }

    void method2(int number, String... args) // String[] causes syntax errors
    {
        if (args == null)
            CConsole.pw.format("args == null\n");
        else
        {
            CConsole.pw.format("args != null    ");
            CConsole.pw.format("args.length %d\n", args.length);
        }
    }
}
```

How can the inconsistency be explained?

The following is included for the person that said that it compiles: To get this error change method1() to use Object[].

**Summary edit:** The lesson seems to be this.  As @Andrew Barber has emphasized, String... is distinct from String[].  They `are not` interchangeable generally, so do not try to treat them the same way (even though I could name reasons why they seem interchangeable).  They **are** interchangeable in the case of main().  In the case of `main()` some people might call this sugar.

Comment: Using `String[]` in function arguments is valid, it shouldn't generate a syntax error. What errors does it print/

Comment: No, just copy the code and try it.

Comment: Why should it give a syntax error? There's nothing wrong with using `String[]` as a parameter

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: @broiyan - it works for me. What errors does it print out for you?

Comment: I think your premise is wrong: `void method1(int number, Object[] args){}` is **not** a syntax error.

Comment: The calls are a syntax error.

Comment: It's an error to declare an array argument and not pass in an array

Comment: @broiyan what does that have to do with the signature of `main()`?

Comment: @EJP: Please note the question is about consistency.

Comment: @broiyan That method accepts a Varargs, which is different from an array, though it works similarly in many cases.

Comment: @broiyan and main() accepts a regular array of strings, which works differently from a Varargs, though similarly in many cases, and is perfectly valid.

Comment: @broiyan So where is the inconsistency? You seem to think that `String[]` itself is illegal syntax. It isn't.

Comment: This is a good question, I believe it is from a begginer who does not understand java very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general , you can use varargs to specify the fact that a method is taking a variable number of arguments as input.  Thus, collections, arrays, and simply individual objects can be sent interchangably in java.  This simplifies methods but there are some gotchas.

Varargs work naturally if

1) They are at the END of a method signature 
2) The type of data you are defining as the var arg is linear (i.e. an array or collection) .

As you can tell, main(String[] args) is thus a natural fit for using var args (that is, args is at the end of your method, it is the last parameter, so it is effectively the same as declaring "String... args" as the last parameter) .  To understand them better I would suggest writing these two methods and watching what the compiler does :

So to answer your question : you got lucky :)  Your method is sending a variable number of arguments to the main method, and new versions of java allow you to get away with var args as input to main.

Comment: "As you can tell, main(String[] args) is thus a natural fit for using var args."  This is kind of vague.  However, the last paragraph is the reason for the acceptance.

Comment: @broiyan: Unfortunately, the last paragraph seems to be inaccurate, since you don't have any methods that call the main method.

Comment: I have a linux OS and an Eclipse IDE that calls it so it seems relevant.

Comment: @broiyan Linux doesn't call your main method. It calls the 'C' main() method in java.exe, which starts a JVM and sets up a JNI call to your Java main() method, which works because your main() method is defined as String[] like millions of main() methods before it since 1995; however since Java 1.5 String... also works.

Comment: @EJP, I will rephrase it.  I have systems that invoke main so it seems relevant.

Comment: @broiyan You mean you have Java code that calls other Java main() methods?

Comment: @EJP, no I invoke main() with bash scripts.

Comment: @broiyan See above. Your bash scripts call Linux; Linux invokes the C main() method in java.exe; the C main() method invokes the JVM via JNI. QED. You don't have any Java code that invokes you Java main(), so your last paragraph remains inaccurate. He didn't 'get lucky'. Java worked as designed.

Answer (score 5):

Varargs were added in later versions of the language. You can in fact use `String ...` over `String[]` in versions of Java that support varargs if you want for `main`.

Comment: Why is main(String[] args) not a syntax error?

Comment: @broiyan Because there is nothing wrong with that syntax.

Comment: But the syntax is disallowed for other methods at the point of invocation.

Comment: You're getting syntax errors because you're *calling* the method incorrectly, not declaring it incorrectly.

Comment: I'm baffled why this answer has so many votes. It doesn't address the question.

Comment: This answer does not address the issue of consistency which is at the core of the question.

Comment: @broiyan, no, the syntax is *not* disallowed, anywhere. String[] is rejected as a *semantic* error when provided as an actual paramter that doesn't match the formal argument. If it was a syntax error, the compiler would say so, literally.

Comment: Heh, I more or less only read the title of the question and only perused the question's content. My answer makes sense if focusing on the question's title. Eh, w/e.

Comment: @RyanStewart - It certainly does answer the question:  *Varargs were added in later versions of the language*.  That's the answer to why `main()` is typically seen with `String[]` instead of `String...`.  And it even goes beyond answering the question to correct the OP's assumption that `main()` cannot use `String...`.  This is, in fact, a very good answer.  It's clear, concise, and correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused about what a valid array parameter looks like. A varargs parameter means you can pass 0 or more of whatever type is defined. If there's no ambiguity, you can pass an array, and the contents of the array will be expanded into the varargs argument.

An array parameter, on the other hand, means you must pass exactly one array. The errors in your example when you replace the varargs arguments with `Object[]` and `String[]` come from how you call the methods. For example:

```
t.method1(0, "a", "b");
```

This is fine for a varargs call, but as soon as you switch the varargs argument to an `Object[]`, the previous method call would need to change to:

```
t.method(0, new Object[]{"a", "b"});
```

or

```
t.method(0, new String[]{"a", "b"});
```

since arrays allow for polymorphism. Conversely, if your method uses varargs, passing an array will work just fine. So you see, there's no inconsistency about the `main` method. Either `String[]` or `String...` works because the problems you're seeing deal with how the method is *called*, not how it's *defined*.

**Update:** Since you seem to be looking for the nitty gritty, the JVMS on [5.2 Virtual Machine Start-Up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#51579) says

> A Java virtual machine starts execution by invoking the method main of
>   some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array
>   of strings.

and on [8.4.1 Formal Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.1), it says

> If the last formal parameter is a variable arity parameter of type T,
>   it is considered to define a formal parameter of type T[]. The method
>   is then a variable arity method. Otherwise, it is a fixed arity
>   method. Invocations of a variable arity method may contain more actual
>   argument expressions than formal parameters. All the actual argument
>   expressions that do not correspond to the formal parameters preceding
>   the variable arity parameter will be evaluated and the results stored
>   into an array that will be passed to the method invocation.

Therefore the main method is always passed a `String[]` when invoked on application startup, and a varargs argument is always received by the respective method as an array, so there's no inconsistency anywhere.

Comment: @broiyan: Updated. If you wanted that, you could've asked for it in the first place.

Comment: It is always a String[] and yet main(String... args) works.  I guess that is the real inconsistency.  (The original inconsistency has been resolved thanks to the efforts of the people who answered.)

Comment: Read the second quote carefully. `String...` is equivalent to `String[]` for all intents and purposes except that `String...` allows some syntactic sugar in the source code. No inconsistencies.

Comment: Just to be clear: I consider the original concern about consistency resolved as follows.  If you are going to use variable argument lists, use dot dot dot.  If you are going to use an array, then use an array in the call and in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The short and only correct answer is that you can use either.

Comment: I think you mean you can use either in `main()` with no changes to the operating system.  You can use either for other methods as long as you do not expect any "artificial assistance".

Comment: @broiyan That's not only what I mean, it's exactly what I said actually, without the irrelevant digression about the operating system having nothing to do with it, which is implicit in the fact that I didn't mention it. Your statement about 'artificial assistance' is completely wrong. If you use ... you can use varargs *or* an array at the calling site, which is what I would call 'artificial assistance'.